# RegEx for Google Analytics Conversion Goal

Tags: regex, google-analytics, checkout, goal-tracking

I've tried to create a regex for the following checkout page:

```
https://checkout.returnonart.com/pay/cs_live_b1sHcLQqcRrQV8C7LXDzSScPgXBp3X4nPkWyCixPl2dj5pEy9oKiq8Y4cO#fidkdWxOYHwnPyd1blppbHNgWnE9dkJGZG59R3BtbzVSMkBNcm1kb2xycjU1YTBLbUR1ZGEnKSdjd2poVmB3c2B3Jz9xd3BgKSdpZHxqcHFRfHVgJz8naHBpcWxabHFgaCcpJ2BrZGdpYFVpZGZgbWppYWB3dic%2FcXdwYHgl
```

The first part is static until `/cs_live_`

This part is dynamic:
b1sHcLQqcRrQV8C7LXDzSScPgXBp3X4nPkWyCixPl2dj5pEy9oKiq8Y4cO#fidkdWxOYHwnPyd1blppbHNgWnE9dkJGZG59R3BtbzVSMkBNcm1kb2xycjU1YTBLbUR1ZGEnKSdjd2poVmB3c2B3Jz9xd3BgKSdpZHxqcHFRfHVgJz8naHBpcWxabHFgaCcpJ2BrZGdpYFVpZGZgbWppYWB3dic%2FcXdwYHgl

So far I have this: `^checkout\.returnonart\.com\/pay\/cs_live_?([A-Za-z0-9\-]*)` but it doesn't work, if I verify this goal via Google Analytics.

Comment: remove `^` or add `https?:\/\/` in your pattern: `^https?:\/\/checkout\.returnonart\.com\/pay\/cs_live_?([A-Za-z0-9\-]*)` see demo: https://regex101.com/r/pkIxW3/2

Comment: Hi @Alireza, thanks for your reply. It still doesn't work, although your suggestion looks legit. Do you have another idea? thanks

Comment: Try this: https://regex101.com/r/pkIxW3/3

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern because probably the cause is the domain in the regex. The domain is not present normally in pagePath in Google Analytics:

```
\/pay\/cs_live_
```

Comment: hi michele, I tried it but doesn't work. I guess that the dynamic part should also be considered. thank you

Comment: If filter is 'match Regex' the dynamic part is irrilevant. Probably the problem is the hostname, try to remove it from regex (with or without dynamic part in the regex), i.e. in my example updated.

Comment: @m4n0 it is the answer.

Comment: It was just an automated response to a review queue. Ignore that. By the looks of it, it looks more like a comment. Anyway, please include more details in your answer because it was in the "Low Quality" queue not flagged by me initially.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your support. Since I found a workaround (button click event), the issue is solved.